# Unable to read cookies in FireFox/Chrome via 302 redirect, but works in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, http-status-code-302

I am breaking my head to figure out a browser specific issue (in Firefox and Chrome). I have spent so much time to try fixing this issue that I have finally thought to create a live demo for the experts here to look into this issue. (Hopefully it pays off)

I have two domains [www.nkmekal.com](http://nkmekal.com) and [www.incessantcoding.com](http://incessantcoding.com)

Please use Firefox/Chrome to replicate the issue:

**Step 1:**

Browse http://www.nkmekal.com/createcookie.aspx

The page just creates a cookie. Below is the code that creates the cookie:

```
    // In On_Load of nkmekal.com/createCookie.aspx
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("DisCookie");
    cookie.Value = "djdjd77676ydjdndgdidjkdnhf";
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    lblCookieInfo.Text = string.Format("<b>Cookie Name:</b> {0} <br/><br/> <b>Cookie Value:</b> {1} <br/><br/> <b>Cookie Expires On:</b> {2}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Expires);
```

**Step 2:**

Now open a new tab in the browser, go to http://www.incessantcoding.com/GoTonkmekal.aspx which basically does a simple 302 redirect to http://www.nkmekal.com/ReadCookie.aspx , below is the code that does this redirect:

```
// In On_Load of incessantcoding.com/GoTonkmekal.aspx
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.nkmekal.com/ReadCookie.aspx");
}
```

However I see the below message: (Please see the code of ReadCookie.aspx page in Step 3)

**“No Cookie Found :(”**

Which means that the domain **www.nkmekal.com** was unable to read the cookie that it created earlier when you’ve browsed **www.nkmekal.com/createcookie.aspx**

**Step 3:**

And the page http://www.nkmekal.com/ReadCookie.aspx just tries to read the above created cookie (in Step 1) and displays cookie data. Below is the code that tries to read the cookie and displays it in the page

```
    // In On_Load of nkmekal/ReadCookie.aspx
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["DisCookie"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
      // Resetting expiry date because the browser never sends expiry date to Server,
      // as cookies expiration dates are irrelevant to servers.
      cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
      lblCookieInfo.Text = string.Format("<b>Yes! I found a cookie</b> <br><br><b>Cookie Name:</b> {0} <br/><br/> <b>Cookie Value:</b> {1} <br/><br/> <b>Cookie Expires On:</b> {2}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Expires);
    }
    else
    {
        lblCookieInfo.Text = "No Cookie Found :(";
    }
```

The above steps work fine only in IE but not in FireFox/Chrome.

Also, if you want to take a peek at the source code of the two domains you can download them at

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1248159/incessantcoding.zip

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1248159/nkmekal.zip

**Why am I trying to do this:**

So, the reason why I am trying to do this is that there are certain operations that I need to perform in the domain **www.incessantcoding.com** if there was a cookie created in **www.nkmekal.com**

And the reason for going with a 302 redirect is that we cannot read cross domain cookies and hence I am trying to get the cookies read from the appropriate domain only (since nkmekal.com can only read its cookies).

Any help/suggestions will be very helpful.

**Update:**
Also quite interestingly, if steps 1 and 3 are performed (leaving out step 2), the cookie value is read in Firefox and Chrome correctly. Its only the 302 way that isn't working.

Comment: yes that was true you cannot read the cross domain cookies...

Comment: Yes! I found a cookie

Cookie Name: DisCookie

Cookie Value: djdjd77676ydjdndgdidjkdnhf

Cookie Expires On: 2/8/2012 11:03:08 PM

Comment: it worked for me. firefox 9.1,brgds

Comment: Thanks for trying out Sebastian...unfortunately I am using firefox 10...

Comment: Hi Patmortech/Sebastian, its so strange that the above steps I mentioned seem to be working if you just click the links in the question description, I just figured that, if you clear the cookies in your browser and try copying and pasting the links instead of clicking the links directly...then I am positive that you will see what I am trying to say...Thanks again for your effort...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out an alternative and it works just fine!
Here is what I've did:

If **nkmekal.com** creates a **DisCookie**...I am issueing a 302 redirect to **incesscantcoding.com** with an encrypted token as a querystring value, then **incessentcoding.com** will create its own **DisCookie** based on the querystring value for its domain, so if I want to know if a cookie exists for **nkmekal.com** I will just look at the Cookies collection for a **DisCookie** in **incessantcoding.com** ... I tested this scenario and it seems to be working in both firefox and chrome...

AND later I figured that even google does similar thing when a user logs into one of their service websites...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

When saving up a cookie, the domain of the website is also being saved - this is made to avoid cross-domain data exchange - which means: once you save up a cookie from one host - it CANNOT be read from another whatsoever.

but, you can pass the cookie's data via the URL from your original host:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["DisCookie"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
         Response.Redirect("http://www.nkmekal.com/ReadCookie.aspx?data=" + cookie.Value);
    }

    else Response.Redirect("http://www.nkmekal.com/ReadCookie.aspx");
}
```

And then just use`data` in ReadCookie.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I even tried what you've suggested, but if you closely look at my implementation, I am issueing a 302 redirect to nkmekal.com only to get the cookie, because nkmekal.com is the host of the cookie...So I am not trying to read the cookie from another whatsoever...